# Can not get a black background JFrame netbeans swing java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I've been trying for a long time to color my JFrame background to black or put an image on it. My GUI contains a main frame and a panel above it and some other buttons on this panel. Any help?

Comment: It would be helpful if you show your code.

Comment: if you are happy with the answers then please go ahead and accept one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried?
If you add a JPanel to your JFrame, it takes upp the full space, then you need to set the background on the JPanel.

```
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
JButton myButton = new JButton("myButton");
myPanel.add(myButton);
myPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
myFrame.add(myPanel);
myFrame.pack();
myFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: @Mohammed Seoudi, so why haven't you accepted the answer yet? I guess you don't want help in the future?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow, still discovering the replays options .

Answer (score 3):

BackGround Color for JFrame just by call getContentPane()

```
import java.awt.*;     import javax.swing.*;                                             public class Main {

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
            frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private Main() {
}}
```